# How to resize image in Ionic 3 without quality reduce and target width and height?

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, resize, ionic3

I want to reduce the size of images taken by camera API but quality reduce is not good. The best thing is to reduce resolution but I don't want to use target width and height for all images.

For example, I want image width be 1280 and image height change automatically by its ratio, but in API I should use exact width and height.

How can I change height dynamic by image ratio???

For now, I use this code:

```
 this.camera.getPicture({
  quality: 60,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: sourceType,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  targetWidth: 1280,
  targetHeight: 1280,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: (source === PictureSource.CAMERA),
  allowEdit: true
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use image resizer native API in camera and it works. when value assign for width and height it turn greater one to the target value and adjust another one by original ratio.. 
here is my code:

```
 this.camera.getPicture({
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: sourceType,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: (source === PictureSource.CAMERA),
  allowEdit: true
})
  .then(imageUri => {
    this.imageResizer.resize({
      uri: imageUri,
      quality: 60,
      width: 1280,
      height: 1280
    }).then(uri => handler(uri))
  })
  .catch(error => console.warn(error))
```

}

Comment: It would be great if you can mention important imports, in this case imports of imageResizer that will make answer more informative.

Comment: I think is https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-resizer

Answer (score 5):

Use these options from the Cordova plugin:

**targetWidth**: Width in pixels to scale image. Must be used with **targetHeight**. Aspect ratio is maintained. (Number)

**targetHeight**: Height in pixels to scale image. Must be used with **targetWidth**. Aspect ratio is maintained. (Number)

Like this

```
var options = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      targetWidth: 400,
      targetHeight: 400,
    };

// Get the data of an image
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
//use the imageData as required.
}, (err) => {

}).catch((error) => {

  })
```