# Ionic Capacitor camera how to reduce image size before uploading

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have set the Capacitor camera plugin with the following options

```
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 20,
  width : 200,
  height : 200,
  allowEditing: false,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Base64
  });
```

After that I take the base64 and upload it to the server. However I am getting images in the 2-5MB range of size (Android). Is there any way of reducing/compressing the size further?

Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150790/how-to-resize-image-in-ionic-3-without-quality-reduce-and-target-width-and-heigh) and other similar postings but they seem to adjust the size by reducing the quality param  and the width and height (which are already low in my case)

Comment: Try removing the `height` or `width` from the image options i.e. keep just one of them.